# Do you trade from a wallet or do you have to send it to an exchange everyday and send back?

Tags: myetherwallet

Sorry, I am new.
I have a variety of crypto in an exchange and I would like to create a wallet as I believe to secure the currency. I have created a MyEtherWallet.
I have noticed there are many fees and charges to get in to the trade. I want to protect my currency.

**Q:** How do I do this process the easiest and cost effective way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental idea for you to understand is the private key.

When you read or hear that an exchange is less safe than having your crypto in a "wallet" what people are saying to you is that the exchange itself, because they hold the private key to your funds, could either steal it or (possibly more likely) lose it or have it stolen from them.

If you hold the private key (as you would if you create a wallet and transfer the crypto out of the exchange) then you have the same burden as the exchange. You have to make sure you don't lose the private key and/or have it stolen from you.

I'm not suggesting that you either should or should not keep your crypto on an exchange, but when you say "I would like to create a wallet to as I believe to secure the currency..." you should be asking yourself what you're securing it from and whether or not it is more likely that you or the exchange will hold the private key more securely.

If you insist on securing your own private key and holding your crypto in your own wallet, then you might want to look into various ways of doing that more safely. I'll just throw out a few "words" without any explanation that you can search for on Google: brain wallet, paper wallet, and especially hardware wallet such as Trezor Nano S.